# There is something wrong with my formulas and I can't figure out which one and where

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//Power function
float power (float base, int exp)
{
    if (exp < 0)
        return 1 / (base * power(base, (-exp) - 1));
    
    if (exp == 0)
        return 1;

    if (exp == 1)
        return base;

    return base * power (base, exp - 1);
}

//Factorial function
int facto (int n)
{
    return n <= 0 ? 1 : n * facto (n - 1);
}

//Cos function
float cosCalc (float rad, int precision)
{
    float cos = 0;

    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < precision; x++)
        {
            cos += power (-1, x) * power (rad, x * 2) / facto (x * 2);
        }

    return cos;
}

//Sin function
float sinCalc (float rad, int precision)
{
    float sin = 0;

    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < precision; x++)
        {
            sin += power (-1, x) * power (rad, 1 + (x * 2)) / facto (1 + (x * 2));
        }

    return sin;
}

//Main function
int main()
{
    int precision = 10;
    int choice;

    //Title and Menu
    //Omitted this part cause it's irrelevant//

    while (true)
    {
        //User Prompt
        cout << endl << "Please enter your choice. => ";
        cin >> choice;
        
        if (choice != 1 && choice != 8 && choice !=9)
            {
                cout << endl << "Please enter a value between 1, 8 and 9.";
            }

        if (choice == 1)
            {
                int angle, anglePh;
                float rad;
                float pi = 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716;
                char angleType;
                float cos = 0;
                float sin = 0;

                cout << endl << "Please enter an angle. => ";
                cin >> angle;
                anglePh = angle;
                //To ensure that the angle given by the user is lower than 360 degrees
                angle %= 360;
                rad = angle * pi / 180;
                cout << anglePh << " degrees = " << rad << " radian";
                cout << endl << "Calculating Cos...";
                cos = cosCalc (rad, precision);
                cout << endl << "Cos = " << fixed << setprecision(precision) << cos;
                cout << endl << "Calculating Sin...";
                sin = sinCalc (rad, precision);
                cout << endl << "Sin = " << fixed << setprecision(precision) << sin;
            }
        
        if (choice == 8)
            {
                //Allows user to change the precision
            }

        if (choice == 9)
            {
                break;
            }
    }   
}
```

Here's the code first, sorry if it is very lengthy.

There is something wrong with my formula which I can't figure out what exactly, as it outputs near correct values when the angle input is a small number, and insanely wrong values when the angle input is something larger. Here's a screenshot of the outputs.

[image: Screenshot of one session]

You can see that when I input 20 and 60, it outputs near perfect answers. Using only Cos as an example, it outputs Cos = 0.9396926165 for 20 when the answer from Google is 0.93969262078, and Cos = 0.4999999106 for 60 when the answer from Google is 0.5. But when the numbers get big, like 300 and 340, the output values go insane as you can see from the screenshot.

Since it outputs the Sin and Cos values nearly correctly at lower inputs, I suspect that there is something wrong with my Power or Factorial functions.

Any ideas?

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this code, what did you see? This is exactly what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use it, this is a good opportunity to learn run your program one line at a time in a debugger, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logic and execution. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. We don't debug other people's code on Stackoverflow, but with your debugger's help you can find all problems in this and all future programs you write, without needing any help.

Comment: floating point error?

Comment: Have you tried this with `double`s rather than `float`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with floating point error, mathematically your algorithm is correct, but your computer cannot hold big numbers with a sufficient precision. You're doing modulo 360, but that will put `rad` between `0` and `2*pi`. That's too much.

What I would recommend is to "shift" your input, `rad`, between `-pi` and `+pi`. I tried the following and it works well :

```
float cosCalc(float rad, int precision)
{
    float cos = 0;
    rad -= std::floor((rad + pi) / (2 * pi)) * (2 * pi); //< HERE 
    ...
}
```

If you prefer not to use `std::floor` you can also shift your angle in degrees between -180 and 180 with

```
angle = (angle + 180) % 360 - 180;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I forgot to mention that I am not supposed to use any math libraries for this, so the floor function wouldn't work. Also could you explain the idea behind shifting my input? And why does your formula put rad between -pi and +pi? Am a new computer science student so I am still new to all these concepts. Thanks for your help, again.

Comment: `std::floor` can be done manually with a cast to int

Comment: Hi, I edited my answer. You can do this operation directly on your angle in degrees, but it means the function will fail if you give rad too big.

Comment: Or cast your double to a long int (or int64_t if you're allowed)

Comment: Thank you that worked! But do you have any idea as to how big of a rad will it fail at though? Am planning to also implement a part where the user inputs his own rad value as well, so I will probably have to limit the rad at a certain range too? || Or does changing my floats into long ints solve the issue as well?

Comment: See's [Quimby's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65648680/14966505) : the error will grow very fast unless you're using a high enough degree in your Taylor's approximation. You can still use the formula I used, but cast into a int or long int instead of using std::floor (if you're allowed)

Answer (score 0):

This is expected, as you know the further you get from the center of the Taylor series, the less precise it gets. Since you expand it at 0, giving it larger angles will require many iterations to get the correct result.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) has a very good picture of this:

[image: Taylor series]

In your case I would suggest to use the known goniometric rules about these two functions and restric yourself to e.g. [-pi/4,pi/4].
Also, your formula will quickly under/overflow for higher values of `x`, you use Horner's method to simplify its evaluation.